# Visual studio 2010 unscoped opaque-enum-declarartion with omitted base

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums

In the following code there are no errors or warnings at compile/link-time

```
enum E;
enum E;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){ }
```

Is it VS2010 bug?

Comment: Given you aren't using `E` it's possible the compiler optimizes-away `E` so it doesn't complain about the double forward-declaration. What happens if you define `E`?

Comment: @Dai For intance g++ doesn't allow this declaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles with VC++ 2010 and later by virtue of MS language extensions
that you can disable with the compiler flag `/Za`.

At first sight,

```
enum E;
enum E;
```

looks just like two forward declarations of `enum E`. In that light, the duplication does not appear
relevant. *N* forward declarations of something are no more or less legal than one, so the effect of
enabling the MS extensions (`/Ze`) would appear to include enabling forward `enum` declarations,
which are illegal per C++03 *or* C++11.

But that appearance is misleading, as the following program shows:

```
#include <iostream>
enum E;
//enum E;
enum E e;
int main()
{
    std::cout << (e == 0) << std::endl;
    return e;
}
```

This also compiles clean with VC++ 2010 or later, proving that
the compiler parses `enum E;` not as *forward declaration* of `E` but as a *definition*.

The language extension here is that `enum E;`, on first sight, is equated with `enum E {}`.

If we uncomment `//enum E;` in the program, it still compiles clean, showing that on second sight
and subsequently, `enum E;` is not *again* parsed as a definition, just as a redeclaration of `E`.

VC++ 2013 supports the C++11 concepts of *scoped* and *based enums*. With extensions disabled,
it will compile and reject declarations as indicated by this piece of code:

```
enum UnscopedBasedEnum : int; // :)
enum UnscopedBasedEnum : int; // :)
UnscopedBasedEnum ube; // :)

enum struct ScopedBaselessEnum; // :)
enum struct ScopedBaselessEnum; // :)
ScopedBaselessEnum sbe;

//enum UnscopedBaseLessEnum; // :(
```

all of which is C++11 compliant.

The declarations of `ube` and `sbe` prove, however, that *none of the
declarations here is a forward declaration*, if *foward declaration* has the customary meaning
of *declaration of an incomplete type*. If `UnscopedBasedEnum`|`ScopedBaselessEnum`
was an incomplete type in these declarations then the declaration of `ube`|`sbe` would
would declare an *object* of incomplete type, and would not compile. Per C++11, the declarations
of `UnscopedBasedEnum` and `ScopedBaselessEnum` are *opaque enum declarations*, meaning
that no enumerator-list is present or implied. But they nevertheless declare complete
types: **p 7.2.3**

> An opaque-enum-declaration is either a redeclaration of an enumeration in the current scope or a declaration
>   of a new enumeration. [ Note: An enumeration declared by an opaque-enum-declaration has fixed underlying
>   type and is a complete type. The list of enumerators can be provided in a later redeclaration with an enum-specifier.
>   —end note ]

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is enum forward declaration. Some compilers (like VS) provide language extensions which enable this behaviour for pre-C++11 standard. You can verify this by disabling the language extensions in your project settings which will result in a compiler error. G++ does not have such extensions but it should compile your code with -std=c++11 after adding size specifiers or when using `enum class` instead.

**Valid in Visual Studio with compiler extensions enabled**

```
enum E;
enum E;
```

**Valid in all compilers supporting C++11**

```
enum class E;
enum class E;

// or

enum E : short;
enum E : short;
```